# Require r function to use objects in global environment rather than copy of object

Tags: r, function, memory, large-data

My (perhaps ignorant) understanding of R is that functions make temporary copies of objects in memory. How can I still use functions to simplify code even if the objects in the global environment are too big to copy? Or is recommended practice to subset only the necessary parts of big objects for functions to manipulate?

Example

```
# load two objects with 10 million rows and 500 columns
big.object.1 <- readRDS(file = "previously.created.dataframe.1")
big.object.2 <- readRDS(file = "previously.created.dataframe.2")

# method 1 with memory use of ~xMB?
big.object.1$recoded.column <- ifelse(big.object.1$old.column > 0,
                                      big.object.1$recoded.column * 2,
                                      big.object.1$recoded.column * 0.5)

# method 2 with memory use of ~2xMB?
new.column_function <- function(data, old.col, recoded.col) {
  data[recoded.col] <- ifelse(data[old.col] > 0,
                                data[recoded.col] * 2,
                                data[recoded.col] * 0.5)
}

new.column_function(data = big.object.1, 
                    recoded.col = 400, 
                    new.col = 401)
```

What is best practice when code is complicated without functions but memory is an issue with functions? How can I avoid copying large objects?

Comment: you can try `data.table` when  memory is an issue with your data.frame.`:=`, fast add, remove and update subsets of columns, by reference.

Comment: @incas56, can you give a simple example as an answer? maybe even transforming the data.frame to a data.table, then manipulating the data.table as specified above? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access objects in the global environment within functions using with `<<-` (instead of `<-`)

```
new.column_function <- function(old.col, recoded.col) {

  ind <- big.object[old.col] > 0

  # Do this 
  big.object[recoded.col] <<- ifelse(ind, big.object[recoded.col][ind] * 2,
                                      big.object[recoded.col][ind] * 0.5) 

  # OR do this
  big.object[recoded.col][ind] <<- big.object[recoded.col][ind] * 2
  big.object[recoded.col][!ind] <<- big.object[recoded.col][!ind] * 0.5

  # Don't think this behaves in the intended way...
  #         ifelse(big.object[old.col] > 0,
  #                                big.object[recoded.col] * 2,
  #                                big.object[recoded.col] * 0.5)
}
```

I do not know if this is better than using `data.table`.

Comment: assume i have big.object.1 and big.object.2. thus, i think i need a function parameter to specify which object (e.g., function(big.object, old.col, recoded.col) ). _will this still avoid making a copy of big.object.2 if i call new.column_function(big.object.2, 400, 401) and use <<- inside the function for assignment_? or perhaps you are suggesting one function for big.object.1 and a second for big.object.2?

Comment: `new.column_function(big.object.2, 400, 401)` would create a copy of `big.object.2`.  by the way your **ifelse** is wrong.

Comment: I think there is a problem in the way you used `ifelse`. Try one of the approaches in the edited solution.

Comment: If you have like couple of big objects to pass, then try using an indicator variable then do an `if(){} else {}` do determine which object to work. Passing the name as a sting could work too.

Answer (score 0):

you can try and use the function `get`and `assign` to only give the name of the objekt to the function and not the whole object

```
new.column_function <- function(nameOfData, old.col, recoded.col) {
  get(nameOfData)[recoded.col] <- ifelse(data[old.col] > 0,
                                data[recoded.col] * 2,
                                data[recoded.col] * 0.5)
}
```

in this case nameOfData is a string with the value `big.object.1` for example